# How to integrate sencha touch plus phone gap

Tags: cordova

I am  new to phonegap.I worked on some samples using sencha touch  and i worked on phonegap to.
   Now i want to develop an application using both sencha touch plus phonegap. 
   Sencha touch for user interface and phonegap for accessing native features of android.

```
                                        Thanks
```

Answer (score 1):

if you already have an application in generating test sencha touch with PhoneGap apk installer to be introducing you to the tool

Follow the steps

1.- Sign up in https://build.phonegap.com/

2.- In your PC create a new Folder with two new folders, "assets" and "test"

3.- In "assets" move all you sencha touch code

4.- In the root of folder, move your icon (of app), the index.html file (the same index used in sencha touch app) and the "config.xml"

5.- add your principal folder to zip and upload to phonegap

6.- Finally you obtain installers to android, windows phone, blackberry, ios, symbian and webos

config.xml https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns       = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id      = "Name mobile"
    version     = "1.0.0">
    <name>name Mobile</name>
    <description>
    </description>
    <author href=""
        email="">
        cmujica
    </author>
    <gap:platforms>
        <gap:platform name="android" minVersion="2.3" />
        <gap:platform name="webos" />
        <gap:platform name="symbian.wrt" />
        <gap:platform name="blackberry" project="widgets"/>
    </gap:platforms>
    <icon src="icon.png" gap:role="default" />
    <gap:splash src="assets/images/bg-blue.png" />
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
    <!-- sample preference specification -->
    <!-- <preference name="autorotate" value="false" readonly="true"/> -->
</widget>
```